# Library for Keycloak+LDAP in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, ldap, authorization, keycloak

I got a NodeJS server application using express. My task is to create an API for user authentication and authorization using credentials from company's LDAP server. This should be performed via Keycloak.

Is there any libraries or techniques for such task?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary other library to hook up between LDAP server and Keycloak.

It called **Federation** by Keycloak terminology.

See this documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/)
you need to know only those red fields information.

[image]

I missed one item
You need Keycloak middle ware **keycloak-connect** library.

It will help express and node-js for connection of Keycloak.
This [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/main/example) can do it.